# proc report text position upper and left corner

Tags: sas

Spend an hour to understand how to locate text in a cell on the left and **upper**  line.

```
proc report data=mydata;
column myvariable ;
define myvariable /display left;quit;
```

[image]

Comment: what do u want to do?
proc report data=mydata; quit; do it, doesnt't it?

Comment: maybe you can show a have and a wanted example?

Comment: @kl78 I added picture

Comment: I cannot reproduce it right now, but did you already tried something like `define myvariable / style={verticalalign=T just=l};` or vjust=t instead of verticalalign?

Comment: @kl78 both variants do not work(

Comment: I could reproduce it with a sample, I guess you have a linebreak in the row where vjust is not working?  I am sorry, I googled a bit but found nothing and I have no idea how to solve this, hopefully somebody else can help you...

Comment: @kl78 Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your data for newline / carriage return characters.

I attempted to reproduce your results and was unable to do so. Your results are already vertical left aligned by default. As you have not entered any header breaks in your syntax, there would not be additional spacing due to wanted/unwanted breaks between headers and data.

```
data list;
    input myvariable $15.;
    datalines;
Hello World!
;

proc report data=list;
    column myvariable;
    define myvariable / display left;
run;
```

[Proc Report Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUV3M.png)

Comment: Hi it is not work. This code locate only left. Try to add second variable, put huge text in it and you will see the real location of myvariable

Comment: what about... define myvariable / display style(column)={vjust=t just=l};  The vjust option allows for top|middle|bottom and the just option allows for left|center|right

Comment: Have you attempted to run the code I provided, instead of trying to use my solutions on your data? If the example I provided works on your computer, then the problem is with your data, and not the code (or SAS). At that point you would need to clean your data to fix the problem.

Comment: You should contact [SAS support](http://support.sas.com).  I have also done an exhaustive google search on this issue and found nothing. Finally, I have only been able to reproduce your results by entering newline characters into my data.